# Apply function that operates on Pandas dataframes on a subset of the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that receives a dataframe and returns a new dataframe, which is the same but with some added columns. Just as an example:

```
def arbitrary_function_that_adds_columns(df):
    # In this trivial example I am adding only 1 column, but this function may add an arbitrary number of columns.
    df['new column'] = df['A'] + df['B'] / 8 + df['A']**3
    return df
```

To apply this function to a whole data frame is easy:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [2,3,4,5]})

df = arbitrary_function_that_adds_columns(df)
print(df)
```

How do I apply the `arbitrary_function_that_adds_columns` function to a subset of the rows? I am trying this

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [2,3,4,5]})

rows = df['A'].isin({1,3})
df.loc[rows] = arbitrary_function_that_adds_columns(df.loc[rows])

print(df)
```

but I receive the original dataframe. The result I'm expecting to get is

```
   A  B  new column
0  1  2         NaN
1  2  3      10.375
2  3  4         NaN
3  4  5      68.625
```

Comment: No. That is part of my trivial function to illustrate what I want to do. My real function is way more complicated.

Comment: Would you confirm your expected results? Instead of [NaN, 5, NaN, 9] I'd expect [3, NaN, 7, NaN], no?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I made that dataframe by hand. Will fix it.

Comment: on what criteria are you likely to generate arbitrary columns? If all you will do is generate one column at a time, try; `df =df.assign(newcolumn = np.where(df['A'].isin([1,3]),df['A'] + df['B'] / 8 + df['A']**3, np.nan))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas.DataFrame.combine_first)

Note that, according to the expected output, you want `rows=[1,3]`, not `rows = df['A'].isin({1,3})`. The latter selects all the rows whose 'A' value is either 1 or 3.

```
import pandas as pd 

def arbitrary_function_that_adds_columns(df):
    # make sure that the function doesn't mutate the original DataFrame
    # Otherwise, you will get a SettingWithCopyWarning 
    df = df.copy()

    df['new column'] = df['A'] + df['B'] / 8 + df['A']**3
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [2,3,4,5]})

rows = [1, 3]
```

```
# the function is applied to a copy of a DataFrame slice 
>>> sub_df = arbitrary_function_that_adds_columns(df.loc[rows])
>>> sub_df

   A  B  new column
1  2  3      10.375
3  4  5      68.625

# Add the new information to the original df 
>>> df = df.combine_first(sub_df)
>>> df

   A  B  new column
0  1  2         NaN
1  2  3      10.375
2  3  4         NaN
3  4  5      68.625
```

---

Here is another way that doesn't involve copying the subset of the DataFrame.

```
def arbitrary_function_that_adds_columns(df, rows='all'):
    if rows == 'all':
        rows = df.index     
    sub_df = df.loc[rows]

    df.loc[rows, 'new column'] = sub_df['A'] + sub_df['B'] / 8 + sub_df['A']**3
    
    return df

>>> df = arbitrary_function_that_adds_columns(df, rows)
>>> df 

   A  B  new column
0  1  2         NaN
1  2  3      10.375
2  3  4         NaN
3  4  5      68.625
```

Comment: +1 Without more information from OP on memory expectations (re: whether data copying is feasible) or type of result being calculated, I expect this is the best solution

Comment: Thanks. This seems to do what I want. Is it possible not to copy, and still keep the action of the `arbitrary_function` fully encapsulated within the function? Is it better for the arbitrary function to return a new data frame containing only the new columns to avoid copy?

Comment: @user171780 Unless you are working with lots of data, and the subset is really big, you shouldn't worry about the copy. Anyway, I've included another solution that doesn't involve copying.  Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you, yes. My data is a few GB so I want to avoid copying.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

With the example you've given:

```py
df['A+B'] = df.loc[df['A'].isin({1,3})].sum(axis=1)
```

or

```py
df['A+B'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['A'].isin({1,3}),['A+B']] = sum_AB(df)
```

More generally:

```py
df.loc[ [row mask], [column mask] ] = [returned df of same shape]

#optionally, use fillna/bfill/ffill as appropriate
```

For more complicated stuff, take a look at `DataFrame.transform` and `DataFrame.apply`; combining those with `df.loc` and an appropriate boolean mask will accomplish what you need.

Comment: I changed the trivial sum function with an arbitrary function that adds a column with an arbitrary calculation using the columns. How would you apply this function? The function can be totally arbitrary, unknown and adds an arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: Is the function you're representing indeed representative? You're passing a `df` *by reference* to it, and then mutating the passed `df` -- is that as intended?

Comment: Is there a better/more correct way to make such functions? Should they return only the new rows and then I add such rows? The thing is that I am adding the rows inside the function so they always have the same names, specified inside the function.

Comment: Without a representative function/transformation, it's difficult to give a definitive answer. You could definitely define a function that operates on a single row, and returns a `pd.Series` with the indices matching what you want your new column names to be, and then call `df.loc[appropriate masking][[columns]] = df[masking].apply(arbitrary_function)`